# How do I insert compressed data with mysqlimport?

Tags: python, mysql

I am using mysqlimport (and python) to import a bunch of records. To save space I'd like to use gzip compression for each of the columns. Does mysqlimport support this?

Right now I am using StringIO to compress each column and then I dump the rows using mysqlimport. Is there a more efficient way? From what I've read StringIO adds unneccessary overhead:

```
# compress each of the columns
for col in d.values():
    stringio = StringIO.StringIO()
    gzip_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=stringio, mode='w')
    gzip_file.write(col)
    gzip_file.close()



#  mysql import script
fh = '/path/to/.sql'
command = ['mysqlimport',
           '--fields-terminated-by=,', 
           '--fields-optionally-enclosed-by="', '-i', '-C',
           '--columns=%s' % ','.join(d.keys()), '--local', fh]
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
_, err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Compressing data prior to insertion defeats many of the advantages that an RDBMS can offer.  If disk space is an issue (though frankly storage space is so cheap these days that it's relatively rare for that to be the case), a better option would be to use the native compression offered by some storage engines.

Comment: "a better option would be to use the native compression offered by some storage engines." This is why I want to use mysql's compression & not the python hack I have above.

Comment: But compression within the storage engine takes place within the RDBMS itself (i.e. on the server), not within `mysqlimport` (which is a client program that uploads data to the server).  To determine what server-side compression options are available in your case, you will need to detail your table's schema (and in particular, the storage engine it uses).

Comment: @eggyal http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/11/mysql-blob-compression-performance-benefits/